Define a new font family in plainTeX
This answer demonstrates how to redefine the \rm family in plainTeX (with LuaTeX).
In a similar way, how can I keep the default Computer Modern font that comes with plainTeX but additionally define a new font family, say \arialFam, so that
{%
\arialFam some regular text, {\bf some bold face text with Arial font}%
}

would select the Arial-Bold font?
MWE:
% !TEX TS-program = luatex
\input{luaotfload.sty}

\newfam\MyFam
\font\arial=Arial
\font\arialbf=Arial-Bold

\textfont\MyFam=\arial
\def\arialFam{\fam\MyFam\arial}
\textfont\bffam=\arialbf

{\arialFam
some regular Arial text. {\bf Bold face Arial text.}
}

\vskip4pt
\rm
Text in Computer Modern, {\bf typed in bold (OK)}.
\bye


Note: Question has already been asked in topanswers. I wasn't content with the solution therefore asking the same question here.

plain tex simply does not hav ethe concept of font families. \bf, \it etc select a single specified font not the bld or italic font from the family of the current font. If you add such a generaic font selection system you are not really using anything like plain tex anymore. You could look at optex for a format in the pplain style but with extensive font support.

oh I notice the linked answer on topanswers says the code shown comes from optex as well.

I noticed that too. Bottom line is it is not possible to achieve such family definitions with plainTeX?

well you can of course define a font selection mechanism but then it makes no sense to call the resulting thing "plain tex" as you almost certainly add more code adding the feature than was in the whole of the plain tex format. plain tex by design is not suitable for document production it is "appendix B: basic macros" just enough to cover the examples in the texbook. You are supposed to define features such as this and add them, but then the resulting thing isn't "plain"

I understand. Then I guess we should close this question?

you could close or you could accept egreg's answer just posted, he does need the points.

The primitive \fam has nothing to do with text, but only with math. The plain TeX command
\def\rm{\fam=0 \tenrm}

(edited for clarity) selects the math font family 0 in math mode and the font \tenrm in text mode. Also \textfont refers to math mode and has no bearing with text mode.
\input{luaotfload.sty}

\let\tenrmLM=\tenrm
\let\tenbfLM=\tenbf

\font\tenrmArial=Arial
\font\tenbfArial=Arial-Bold

\def\LM{%
  \let\tenrm=\tenrmLM
  \let\tenbf=\tenbfLM
  \rm
}
\def\Arial{%
  \let\tenrm=\tenrmArial
  \let\tenbf=\tenbfArial
  \rm
}

\rm % just for safety

{\Arial some regular Arial text. {\bf Bold face Arial text.}}

Text in Computer Modern, {\bf typed in bold (OK)}.

\bye


It's much better to use a format with a font selection scheme such as OpTeX, if you don't want to use LaTeX.
